# Flask. Roles_required decorator no more working after Flask upgrade

Tags: python, flask

When I upgrade my Flask project (Flask 1.0.2, Flask-Login 0.4.1) to the latest versions, the roles_required decorator no longer works. The "login" itself is working.

models.py

```
...
from flask_user import UserMixin

class ApiUserRoles(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'apiuser_roles'
    user_id = db.Column("user_id", db.Text, db.ForeignKey("public.apiuser.id", use_alter=True), nullable=False,
                        primary_key=True)
    role_id = db.Column("role_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("public.apiroles.id", use_alter=True), nullable=False,
                        primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column("description", db.String(50))


class ApiUser(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'apiuser'
    id = db.Column("id", db.Text, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    roles = db.relationship('ApiRoles', secondary='public.apiuser_roles')
    password_hash = db.Column("password_hash", db.Text, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column("description", db.String(50))
```

auth.py

```
from flask import session
from flask_httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth
from flask_user import UserManager


class ApiUserManager(UserManager):
    auth = None

    def __init__(self, app, db, User, auth):
        super(ApiUserManager, self).__init__(app, db, User)
        self.auth = auth

    def unauthenticated_view(self):
        return self.auth.auth_error_callback(401)

    def unauthorized_view(self):
        return self.auth.auth_error_callback(403)


class ApiAuth(HTTPBasicAuth):
    def authenticate(self, auth, stored_password):
        result = super(ApiAuth, self).authenticate(auth, stored_password)
        if result and auth:
            session['user_id'] = auth.get('username')
        return result


auth = ApiAuth()
```

init.py

```
from auth import ApiUserManager, auth as auth_object
from models import ApiUser

def init(app):
    app.app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.getenv('database_url')
    db.init_app(app.app)
    db.app = app.app

    # Flask-User settings
    app.app.config['USER_APP_NAME'] = 'api'
    app.app.config['USER_ENABLE_EMAIL'] = False
    ...
    
    user_manager = ApiUserManager(app.app, db, ApiUser, auth_object)
    
    # the following lines are no more working
    login_manager = user_manager.login_manager

    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
        try:
            return ApiUser.query.filter(ApiUser.id == user_id).first()
        except:
            return None
...

def create_app(config_name):
    app = connexion.FlaskApp(__name__)
    with app.app.app_context():
        init(app)
    return app.app
```

When I add a breakpoint in my load_user method, the "old Flask application" is hitting the breakpoint. The "new Flask" does not reach this method.

When I call some endpoint e.g.

```
@auth.login_required
@roles_required('Read')
def getFoo():
...
```

I get an "Unauthorized Access"

When I remove the @roles_required decorator from the endpoint, everything works fine.
Has someone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

A full `pip freeze` output from both pre- and post-upgrade environments would have been helpful (and please do attach them if this answer does not resolve the issue). Still, the most likely cause is an upgrade of the package `Flask-HTTPAuth` from version 3.x (or earlier) to version 4.x. The [changelog](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-HTTPAuth/blob/main/CHANGES.md) entry for version 4.0.0 lists the following change:

> - Pass HTTP status code to error callback ([commit](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-HTTPAuth/commit/fc8bcd6772b53ef5cc14cd4c6199d63cd2c71f30))

The linked commit shows that the `default_auth_error` function now requires a `status` argument. While efforts were made to keep backward-compatibility with custom callbacks (the `try:.. except TypeError:` block), this argument is required if no custom callback is specified. If a status is not provided to the default callback, python would raise an exception as posted:

```
TypeError: default_auth_error() missing 1 required positional argument: 'status'
```

Changing the following code in `auth.py` should resolve this problem:

```
class ApiUserManager(UserManager):
    ...

    def unauthenticated_view(self):
        return self.auth.auth_error_callback(401)  # HTTP unauthorized

    def unauthorized_view(self):
        return self.auth.auth_error_callback(403)  # HTTP forbidden
```

Note: This is not a recommendation for the specific status codes, just an example for a solution. Adjust the actual codes to fit the application's requirements for each case.

Comment: Thx for the reply. Adding the status_code fixes the issue. But does not solve the "problem in general". I'm still Unauthorized. This "role mechanism" no longer seems to work...(with my code)

Comment: I've adjusted my original question/post....